# .NET Core publish work only with Production environment

Tags: .net-core

I have .NET Core 3.1 app and I publish it to file system.

In `web.config` file I have:

```
<environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" value="Development" />
```

And in `launchSettings.json` I have:

```
"App": {
  "commandName": "Project",
  "launchBrowser": true,
  "environmentVariables": {
    "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
  },
  "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:5000/"
}
```

When I launch app `dotnet App.dll` I have error with wrong DB connection but if I copy `appsettings.Production.json` file then everything is fine. What's wrong? Why I can't use Development environment?
How to set up Development environment properly? What did I miss?

Comment: sorry i don't understand exactly .. do you want tio use PRODUCTION OR DEVELOPMENT configuration?

Comment: I want to use Development

Comment: so in publish profile set it ..and create a file app settings called appsettings.Development.json

Comment: I already have appsettings.Development.json file but app for some reasons don't want to take params from that file.Where I need to set Development? https://www.screencast.com/t/BYx14Xrh0N

Comment: Do you have an env var set?  setx ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT "Development"  Is your UI set to run production?

Comment: Do you mean I need to execute in command line `setx ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT "Development"` before `dotnet App.dll`? If yes, it doesn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strange thing, when I publish from VS, it always used Production environment although I set Development everywhere where I can (web.config, launchSettings.json, .pubxml, .csproj).

But when I use .NET CLI and execute `dotnet publish` then it uses Development environment by default, I set Development environment only in launchSettings.json file.

Not sure if it's VS bug but for me using of .NET CLI was solution of problem.